# What is the bootloader function in Microcontrollers?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, bootloader

In PC Bootloader is necessary to show where BIOS is located in memory, and then BIOS starts actual operating system etc.

But how is situation in embedded, where MCUs actually usually don't have operating system?

What is function of bootloader here?

Comment: In a PC, BIOS starts first, loads a bootloader or whatever is present at predetermined location. Not the other way around. Bootloader gives you flexibility on what to do next. (Same as in embedded)

Comment: But "In PC Bootloader is necessary to show where BIOS is located in memory" does not make any sense. BIOS is the thing that load and executes something that may eventually load and execute something that is called a bootloader for some OS. And MCUs can have an OS and running it does not require a bootloader.

Comment: @Mat Depends *which* bootloader we are talking about... You are referring to the OS bootloader, but there many subcomponents with bootloaders that run much earlier in the modern processors. BIOS is being loaded by some kind of bootloader too.

Answer (score 3):

The term *bootloader* is generic - it can mean many things depending on the exact context.

There's a bit of history that might make things a little clearer:

Early computers had no means of storing startup code, so you would have to enter a small piece of code via switches or other means to *bootstrap* the computer. This small piece of code might load another piece of code from paper tape, punch card or a disk device. That piece of code might be named a *loader*. As time went on, the words got contracted and combined. *bootstrap* got shorted to *boot* and got combined with *loader* to *bootloader*.

In short, *bootloader* generally refers to a piece of code that has the means of loading more code.

To add to the confusion, you can have multiple bootloaders.

eg: The original IBM PC. The 8088 cpu on reset would get the start address of the code from a fixed location which was usually in ROM. For the PC this was the BIOS rom. After doing some initialisation, the BIOS would try to read the first sector off the floppy disk. If that failed it would run the ROM basic.

The first sector of the floppy would have a small bootloader that would usually load PCDOS/MSDOS into ram and execute it.

Newer PCs are a little more complex as there is a system controller microcontroller that initialises some hardware then loads the bios from a serial flash into ram then starts the main processor. The main cpu takes over and executes the BIOS which then attempts to read a known sector from disk. This sector has another bootloader that knows how to load the OS. So we have multiple layers of bootloader in this instance.

With microcontrollers, we might have no bootloader, one or many bootloaders. There is no one solution. You need to understand the specific microcontroller as to how it works in terms of startup.

Some examples:

*Microchip/Atmel AVR Mega328* (as used in the popular Arduino UNO).
These chips have internal flash and on reset will execute code for address 0. To load the code into flash there are two methods - parallel programming and ISP which is a serial protocol. This requires specific hardware to do this. You would either plug the chip into a special programmer to load the code or provide a connector or other means on your pcb in order to connect a ISP programmer.

Remember that for the most part a microcontroller will only run one program for most of its life.

At this point there is no bootloader and no requirement for one. However, you might want some means to change the code with having to use an ISP programmer.

The Arduino UNO allows you to update the code with one click on their application. To do this they implement a bootloader. Their bootloader uses the chip's usart and implements a serial protocol to transfer new code via serial via USB. This bootloader is programmed into a specific area of the on chip flash.

*ESP32* The Espressif chip has very little on chip flash. It expects to have an external serial flash chip that has the code. It has an internal rom with a bootloader that basically does two things - read the code from the serial flash into it's ram and execute or implement a serial protocol to allow downloading new code into the serial flash. To get the ESP32 to load new code via serial, you need to reset the device with a GPIO pin held low. When you do this, it sends out a message on the serial inviting you to load new code. You run an application on your PC that knows how to talk the protocol to load new code.

Now, say you want to load new code via WiFi or Bluetooth? That would be convenient. To do this you have another bootloader that does this. The point here is that you can write a bootloader(s) to implement any means you wish. As such, this bootloader is effectively just another application.

In short, bootloaders come in all shapes and sizes.

Answer (score 2):

A microcontroller's boot loader does a subset of the things a BIOS does. At minimum, it prepares the machine for loading the main operating system, even if that ‘operating system’ is just a simple application loop.

In most systems, the bootloader does the following:

- sets up the hardware (DRAM controller, etc.)
- sets up memory (clears RAM, loads interrupt vectors)
- sets up a console and possibly a debug environment
- initializes and starts any needed interfaces (e.g., disk, flash, network, UI)
- finds and mounts a filesystem containing the main OS
- loads the OS and launches it

Simple systems that have only memory will simply branch to the main OS after the initial steps. More complex ones will load a kernel from nonvolatile storage or from a network, possibly validate the image, then start it. "Validate the image" could be a basic integrity check (e.g., compute and compare a hash) or decrypt a signed OS image with a local key.

A system that uses a local cache / buffer memory has the additional step of first loading a 'mini-boot' loader in its local RAM, which then inits low level hardware, DRAM, interrupts and cache, and then gets the *rest* of the boot image to DRAM. Secure boot processes add encryption / validation to this step, using tamper-resistant security blocks within the chip.

BIOS has these layers and steps, and adds complex driver support and extended system configuration utilities. Over the decades, BIOS has endured considerable 'mission creep' from its intention as a Basic I/O System. BIOS is also very specific to x86, and is also closely tied to the motherboard / chipset manufacturer. As a consequence, it's sometimes very hard to get needed support built in to BIOS (such as flexible PCIe lane bifurcation) unless you're a large customer or have the resources to make your own BIOS.

The open-source community has GRUB and other options as alternatives to BIOS. Embedded, non-x86 systems will usually use a run-time environment (including bootloader) supplied from the SoC or embedded OS vendor, or possibly something like GRUB.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the processor, in the 8088 the processor loads one instruction from  0x7c00 on the I/O and the first 64kB of memory. The chips used to be separate IC's now the ram rom and processor can all be manufactured on the same IC. So on a microcontroller the first thing the state machine of the processor does is reset and then start loading instructions from one location in the ROM. The ROM can setup a basic operating system (like a memory manager) and start running programs.